# How to update cocoapods dependency?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, sdwebimage

I am trying to use this library:  https://github.com/calm/KenBurns

The issue is this - When I try to add this cocoapod to my project I get the following warning.

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SDWebImage":   In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
>       SDWebImage (= 3.8.2, ~> 3.8.2)
>
> In Podfile:
>       SDWebImage (~> 4.0)
>
> Specs satisfying the `SDWebImage (~> 4.0), SDWebImage (= 3.8.2, ~>
>   3.8.2)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

I'm using SDWebimage already in my project separately and this cocoapod also has SDWebimage inside it as a dependency. My question is how do I solve this issue above? How do I update SDWebimage inside this cocoapod to match what I have in my project?

Thank you for the help! I never experienced this before using pods.

Update: Podfile

> Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project platform :ios, '10.0'
>
> target 'Sample-Project' do
>
> Comment the next line if you're not
>    using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks   use_frameworks!
>
> # Pods for Sample-Project
>   pod "KenBurns"
>   pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'

Comment: Please add your Podfile here

Comment: @DanielGhrenassia Please check updated question above

Comment: check your iOS Deployement target in Xcode it needs to be higher than iOS 8.0, also you can try to remove the specific pod version for SDWebImage -> remove this '~> 4.0' and do pod update

Comment: @DanielGhrenassia The project is higher than 8.0 already (11.0). How would I update the pods inside the KenBurns library?

Comment: SDWebImage is a dependency, it will be installed directly with KenBurns, you can just remove the line pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0' entirely and just go with pod "KenBurns"

Comment: remove `pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'` and check if it works. Maybe KenBurns uses some newer version

Comment: How can I update the SDWebimage in KenBurns? or remove it completely?